# emacs ORG-mode "headless" export-as commands?

Tags: emacs, html, latex, org-mode

When I use `org-export-as-latex` or `org-export-as-html` orgmode turns my buffer into a `.tex` file or `.html` file. But I don't want all the extra junk that it adds to the file: I want to handle the `documentclass` and everything myself and just `\input` the org mode generated file. (Or the analogous things for html with php).

So if my org file just has:

```
* Section
- Stuff
- Things
```

I want the org mode command to output *just*

```
\section{Section}
\begin{itemize}
\item Stuff
\item Things
\end{itemize}
```

Without any of the extra `\tableofcontents` junk that ORG adds to it. I know I could define my own kind of `#+LaTeX_CLASS` that could add the packages I want and so on, but I don't want to do things that way (and that wouldn't remove the `\maketitle` or the spurious `\vspace*` that ORG insists on inserting.

Is there a command to do this "headless" parsing and converting? I had a look but it's not obvious from the documentation. Presumably some low level ORG command is doing the parsing and converting I want, but I couldn't find what it was called from looking at the docs and `C-h` pages...

This is not a question about HTML or LaTeX but about emacs ORG mode. So don't kick it off to some other site...

Comment: Check the prototype and documentation for `org-export-as-latex`. There is a flag called `body-only` which will do part of the job. You can also pass a property list for overriding default settings.

Comment: Also, if you need real minimalism, have a look at the generic exporter at http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-export-generic.html

Comment: @Juancho could you explain how to pass a flag to a command? Maybe as part of an answer to this question?

Comment: Just for trying, `M-:` then enter `(org-export-as-latex nil nil nil nil t)` (the last `t` means true for the body-only parameter). You'll get a message indicating the tex buffer created. If you like the result, you can make a command or keybinding to call this.

Comment: @Juancho I get "trailing garbage following expression" and no output...

Comment: Maybe we're using different org-mode versions; I use the latest development commit. Please have a look at the arguments for this function (type `F1-f org-export-as-latex`) and check that there is a 5th argument called BODY-ONLY.

Comment: @Juancho the arguments are in a different order, but I still can't seem to get it working. I looked at `org-export-generic` but that didn't work either: `Cannot open load file: org-export-generic`

Comment: For the record, the right invocation for me was ` (org-export-as-latex 3 nil nil nil t nil)` Could you add an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For LaTeX output, here are some options for getting cleaner output:

The function `org-export-as-latex` actually takes several parameters, one of which is a flag called BODY-ONLY.

The prototype for this function is `(org-export-as-latex ARG &optional HIDDEN EXT-PLIST TO-BUFFER BODY-ONLY PUB-DIR)` for OrgMode 7.5.

You can try the output by evaluating the LISP call explicitly:

```
M-: (org-export-as-latex nil nil nil nil t) RET
```

where the `t` symbol indicates the body-only option. This will create a new buffer with the LaTeX output. (RET means pressing the return key)

A shortcut for the above is to call `org-export-region-as-latex`. This is an interactive function which you can call with `M-x`. Its only argument is the body-only flag.

For example, you can select the whole buffer (via `C-x h`), then call this function with a prefix argument (to give a non-nil value to body-only):

```
C-u M-x org-export-region-to-latex RET
```

Now you'll have a new buffer selected with the LaTeX output and no header / footer / titles / TOC added.

This idea works also with `org-export-region-as-html`.

There is also a contributed package `org-export-generic` that lets you define an exporter completely: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-export-generic.html

P.S. I'm using the latest development version of OrgMode 7.5